# Is there a reason I am getting no rows selected for this NOT IN nested query

Tags: sql

Query:

```
SELECT teamid 
FROM team
WHERE teamid NOT IN (SELECT team_teamid FROM gymnast);
```

Tables:

[TEAM table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0jNZ.png)

[Gymnast table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYhUb.png)

I have been trying to figure this out for a while, any information would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what db you use?

Comment: sql developer..

Comment: It's due to the nulls.  non_null_value NOT IN (... some list with nulls ...) will never produce true.

Answer (score 2):

[The fiddle for oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a06d479d3e3dbddfdd0300af7f34d4c2)

`val NOT IN (some list)` means the value does NOT match every entry in the list.

But if one entry in the list is `null`, `value <> null` can never be true for that entry, which means the entire `NOT IN` expression can never be true.

See the following examples:

```
WITH team (teamid) AS (
        SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 3 FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 4 FROM DUAL
     )
   , gymnast (team_teamid) AS (
        SELECT    1 FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT    2 FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT    2 FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT    4 FROM DUAL
     )
SELECT teamid FROM team WHERE teamid NOT IN (SELECT team_teamid FROM gymnast)
;
```

Result:

| TEAMID |
| --- |
| 3 |

Case 2 with nulls in the list:

```
WITH team (teamid) AS (
        SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 3 FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 4 FROM DUAL
     )
   , gymnast (team_teamid) AS (
        SELECT    1 FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT    2 FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT null FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT    4 FROM DUAL
     )
SELECT teamid FROM team WHERE teamid NOT IN (SELECT team_teamid FROM gymnast)
;
```

Result:

| TEAMID |
| --- |

No rows in result, due to the `gymnast` with a `null` `team_teamid`.

Comment: In theory though - this could work though if they used COALESCE for the column with nulls to evaluate to something that wouldn’t be in the other table within the NOT IN subquery right? Like “where teamid not in (select COALESCE(team_teamid, ‘PIZZAMONSTER’) as team_teamid FROM gymnast)

Comment: Or if they added “where team_teamid IS NOT NULL” into the subquery, assuming that when it’s null it’s irrelevant

Comment: @procopypaster That's right.